# Datepicker dateFormat doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datepicker

The format of my datepicker won't change. Tried a lot of things, looks like it's impossible..

my code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
                var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
                date_input.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    container: container,
                    autoclose: true,
                    startDate: '+1w',
                    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "4,6",
                    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3,5",
                    orientation: "auto",
                })
            })
        </script>
```

also tried:

```
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
format: 'dd-mm-yy'
format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
```

Comment: let me know which library used for datepicker?

Comment: There're probably several dozen jQuery-based datepicker libraries. You absolutely need to specify which one you are using (Twitter Bootstrap's?) or we won't be able to help.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: month and date should be in caps and attribute name is `format`, check below format where M and D in capital

`format: DD/MM/yyyy`

Comment: that gives: Thursday/May/2017

Comment: after i changed it to yours and go back to my:      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
it worked. So thank you..